Karate in visual studio code
Scenario:
Given url 'http://myhost.com/v1/cats'
And request {name: 'Billie'}
When method post
Then status 201
And match response == {id: '#notnull', name: 'Billie'}
Given path response.id
When method get
Then status 200
Output
Error: there is no registered task type 'karate'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?
Error: there is no registered task type 'karate'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?
But I already installed Karate runner in visual Studio code
I need Solution to this problem

Use official plugin from this link - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karatelabs.karate. Or you can search for Karate in Extensions Market place in vs code and install it. But the extension is a paid one. If you are not looking for a paid one, you can  always use java runner class and specify the feature file there.
